# Mockito: Mock class<T> object

Tags: mockito, powermock

Apologies if it's already been discussed but I didn't find any solutions.

Problem -
Trying to mock an object of my Class of some type (e.g. class)

Writing test case of method xyz() where i need to mock SomeClass.class as mentioned in below code snippets

```
void xyz() {
..
MyOtherClass.staticMethod(SomeClass.class);
..
}

MyOtherClass {
..
<T> T staticMethod(Class<T> clazz) {
}
...
}
```

1. Using power mockito
2. Tried (Class) Mockito.mock(Class.class), which is not working.

I hope above code clears the problem. Any help much appreciated.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, found solutions:

Run your test case with PowerMockRunner by annotating as follow:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ MyOtherClass.class, MainClass.class})
```

Mock your static method and supply expected object of your class of specific type:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyOtherClass.class);
PowerMockito.when(MyOtherClass.staticMethod((Class<SomeClass>) SomeClass.class)).thenReturn(...);
```

Thanks

Answer (score -4):

Try `Mockito.mock(Class<T>.class);`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think its even compile. We cannot use generics in java this way.