# Mock Class instance in java

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

Is there a way to mock `Class` instance in java

```
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

 public <T> T search(Class<? extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<ENTITY>> 
specExecutor,
  Class<? extends Converter<DTO, ENTITY>> objConverter) {
 JpaSpecificationExecutor jpaSpecificationExecutor = context.getBean(specExecutor);
 Converter converter = context.getBean(objConverter);
}
```

I have to unit test the above method, i am using Mockito.

The issue is, when i use:

```
  Mockito.when(context.getBean(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(new MyJpaSpecificationExecutor());
```

The above will not work for `context.getBean(objConverter);` // `ClassCastException`

Is there a way in `Mockito` or `PowerMockito` to achieve this?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943176/mockito-mock-classt-object

Comment: @pvpkiran It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500312/mockito-match-any-class-argument - PowerMock is not a good idea.